# Merging two dataframes by two columns resulting in blank df

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, merge

I have one dataframe (qtpo_liver_dates) of liver transplant patients and their procedure dates. In this dataframe, each patient has their own procedure date. Another dataframe (labs_v500) of the same cohort shows lab dates and results, and visit dates including the procedure date, but mostly dates not of interest. I want to merge the dataframes on the patient and procedure date in R (i.e. filter labs_v500 by the actual procedure date). I tried the following but returned a blank dataframe

```
df <- merge(qtpo_liver_dates,labs_v500, by = c("patient_num","liver_date"))
```

Could someone explain the best way to do this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: The format of "liver_date" is different between the two data frames, so `merge` cannot match any rows, and produces an empty data frame. Try the `lubridate` package to quickly reformat the dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first tell R that both `liver_date` columns are dates. The function `as.Date` let you do that.

So let`s say we got `df1` and `df2`

```
date1<-(c("2007-08-01", "2004-10-05", "2014-03-09"))#Year - Month - Day
date2<-(c("8/1/07", "10/5/04", "3/9/14"))#Month/Day/Year 
x<-(c(1:3))
z<-c(11:13)
w<-c(11:13)


df1<-data.frame(date1, x, z)
str(df1$data1)
  
df1

> df1
       date1 x  z
1 2007-08-01 1 11
2 2004-10-05 2 12
3 2014-03-09 3 13

df2<-data.frame(date2, x, w)
str(df2$date2)

df2 
> df2
    date2 x  w
1  8/1/07 1 11
2 10/5/04 2 12
3  3/9/14 3 13
```

With `as.Date` you tell the format of the column in which the dates are, for `df1` is a Y-M-D

```
df1$date1<-as.Date.character(df1$date1,format="%Y-%m-%d")
str(df1$date1)
```

And for `df2` is m/d/y

```
df2$date1<-as.Date.character(df2$date2,format="%m/%d/%y")
str(df2$date1)
```

We recode the `df2$date2` in `df2$date1` to match the name of the column, this will be needed by the `merge` function later, in your case you could recode in the same column because they have the same name:

```
df3<-merge(df1,df2, by =c("date1", "x" ) )
df3

>df3
       date1 x  z   date2  w
1 2004-10-05 2 12 10/5/04 12
2 2007-08-01 1 11  8/1/07 11
3 2014-03-09 3 13  3/9/14 13
```

As you can see, `z` and `w` match perfectly, so we know we did it right.

In your data:

`df1` = `qtpo_liver_dates`

`df2` = `labs_v500`

`date1`, `date2` = `liver_date`

`x` =  `patient_num`

`z` = Some column in `qtpo_liver_dates`

`w` = Some column in `labs_v500`

Answer (score 0):

It's best when you are posting questions here to include some sample data in a way that's easy to work with. Rather than a picture you can do `dput(head(my_data_frame)` to get a sampling of your data that you can post in your question. Since you didn't do that I created a small subset of your data to illustrate a solution.

Here's the same data I created to simulate your problem:

```r
qtpo_liver_dates <- data.frame(
  patient_num = c(1, 2, 3),
  liver_date = c("2007-08-01", "2004-10-05", "2014-03-09")
)

labs_v500 <- data.frame(
  patient_num = c(1, 2, 3),
  liver_date = c("8/1/2007", "10/5/2004", "3/9/2014"),
  other_data = c("Other Data A", "Other Data B", "Other Data C")
)
```

As @jdobres mentioned, `merge()` didn't work because the format of `liver_date` varies in the two data sets. This is easily corrected, however, with functions from the `lubridate` package.

We'll correct the date formats with two calls to `lubridate` functions. In the first we'll use `mdy()` which expects data in a month-day-year format. In the second we'll use `ymd()` which looks for data in a year-month-day format. In both cases we'll replace the character strings in the `liver_date` variables of your data frames with the new date variables.

```r
library(lubridate)

qtpo_liver_dates$liver_date <- ymd(qtpo_liver_dates$liver_date)
labs_v500$liver_date <- mdy(labs_v500$liver_date)
```

Now `merge()` should work, and since the common variable names are the same between the two data frames there's no need to specify them explicitly.

```r
merge(qtpo_liver_dates, labs_v500)
```

**Output**:

```
  patient_num liver_date   other_data
1           1 2007-08-01 Other Data A
2           2 2004-10-05 Other Data B
3           3 2014-03-09 Other Data C
```